Current sense GND planes Power & Signal
I couldn't find a clear answer anywhere.
I have a battery powered device which therefore has a VBAT+ and a VBAT-.
The battery is used through some power stages (which contain MOSFETs which are driven with GND = VBAT- reference) and goes through a shunt resistor which is then amplified by an INA180B1 IC which goes to a MCU.
My question is the following:
Shall the GND of MCU be the same as the VBAT-. I am not talking of full insulation, but rather Net Ties or ferrite beads. I am looking for some documentation on this subject.
Edit : Here are few schematics :



Depends. Please add a schematic.

If you want to have the MCU supervise, then it needs to be connected over the battery terminals.
